# How do I analyze if jQuery has printed the text when resizes the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, jquery-events, window-resize

I have a problem at the time to display some text with **jQuery** on my site.

I have the next code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">something</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).resize( function() {
    if($(document).width() <= 480) {
        $('#one').css('display','none');
        if( !$('#two').legth ) {
            $('#one').after('<div id="two">something else</div>');
        };
    }
    else {
        $('#one').css('display','inline');
        $('#two').delete();
    };
});
```

When resizes the window, the **div#two** is printed repeatedly, and if stops and then resizes again it prints again and again.

I don't know what is wrong in the code. Please, all help will be welcome.

Comment: Browsers fire the "resize" event very, very frequently, the whole time the window is being resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get it, but If you just want it to work once:

```
$(window).one('resize', function() {
    $('#one').hide();
    if( !$('#two').length )
        $('#one').after('<div id="two">something else</div>');
});
```

and it's `length`, not `legth`, and that could be the reason for the `if` failing, if so, just replace `one()` with `on()` ?

Comment: That works! Thanks you! But that isn't what I expected. I need that the event fires more times. I have edited the code to explain me better.

Comment: Just replace `one` with `on` and the resize event will keep firing, but the element will only be appended once.

Comment: I've try it too, and the element is printed more than once again and again.

Comment: @AlbertFM - Not sure what you mean then, as it seems to work just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S3sjS/1/).

Comment: you'r right!. My fail was here:

`if( !$('#two').legth )`

The correct is `.length`
Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you very much!